# Calabi Yau threefolds

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds, hodge-theory

Let be $X$ a Calabi-Yau manifold (i.e. Kahler, compact with trivial canonical bundle) with $\dim(X) = 3$. Let $\phi : A \mapsto B$ a proper holomoprhic submersion such that $X_{t_{0}} := \phi^{-1}(t_{0}) = X$ for some $t_{0} \in B$.

I consider the following map $t \mapsto H^{3,0}(X_{t}) \subset H^{3}(X_{t}) \simeq H^{3}(X)$ which is valued in $\mathbb{P}(H^{3}(X))$ (since $H^{3,0}(X_{t})$ is of dimension $1$ by Serre duality). **I would like to show near $t_{0}$, the image is a manifold.**

This comes from Voisin's book  Hodge theory and complex algebraic geometry, chapter 10. I already know from this book that this map is a holomorphic immersion and that is differential at $t_{0}$ maps $T_{t_{0}}B$ in $\operatorname{Hom}(H^{3,0}(X), H^{2,1}(X))$.

I wish you a good day.

Comment: Where in Voisin's book?

Comment: Chapter 10 page 243. Thanks for your interrest.

Comment: I'll do my best to take a look later today :)

Comment: Many thanks, it is cool from you to help me. I try to show the map $t \mapsto H^{3,0}(X_{t})$ is an embeding. But I did nothing more than use a theorem that tholds me it's an immerssion.

Comment: In fact, my problem is that i don't know how $A$ and $B$ are construct  (they both came from Bogomolov-Tian-Todorov theorem).